# Подсчет количества элементов лежащих в диапазоне на скользящем окне

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

`D['T']` - температура. задана

`D['K']` - верхняя допустимая граница. задана

> D['T'] = [5,6,5,6,6,7,7,7,9,9.5,9,8,8,8,8.5,9,10,11,11,10,10,11]
>
> D['K'] = [7.25,8.25,7.25,8.25,8.25,9.25,9.25,9.25,11.25,11.75,11.25,
> 10.25,10.25,10.25,10.75,11.25,12.25,13.25,13.25,12.25,12.25,13.25]

**Пример. Алгоритм расчета для 20й точки:**

1. Фиксируем значения D["K"] и D["T"] в 20й точке
2. Считаем количество точек D["K"] на интервале 9 - 19, значение которых меньше зафиксированного в пером шаге D["K"] и больше зафиксированного в пером шаге D["T"]

Хочу получить такие расчеты для каждой точки.

Пыталась так:

```
D["Col"] = ((D["K"] - D["T"]).gt(0)).rolling(10, min_periods=1).sum().astype("int")
```

Но всегда получается 10 элементов. Т.к. скользит разница, которая всегда положительная, как не считать точки, которые выше диапазона понять не могу

Comment: У вас условие в вопросе и на картинке несколько не сходится. Вероятно, на картинке более четко описана задача, но там тоже ошибка, поскольку диапазон зеленого окна - 11 точек, а не 10. Верным ответом там должно быть 8 красный точек в диапазоне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
def find_range(window):
    window=pd.Series(window) # for backward compability
    frame = df.loc[window.index]
    rng = frame[(frame["K"]<=frame["K"].iloc[-1])&(frame["K"]>=frame["T"].iloc[-1])]    
    return len(rng)

df["C"] = df["K"].rolling(window=10).apply(find_range)
```

тогда `df` будет:

```
       T      K    C
0    5.0   7.25  NaN
1    6.0   8.25  NaN
2    5.0   7.25  NaN
3    6.0   8.25  NaN
4    6.0   8.25  NaN
5    7.0   9.25  NaN
6    7.0   9.25  NaN
7    7.0   9.25  NaN
8    9.0  11.25  NaN
9    9.5  11.75  2.0
10   9.0  11.25  5.0
11   8.0  10.25  6.0
12   8.0  10.25  7.0
13   8.0  10.25  7.0
14   8.5  10.75  7.0
15   9.0  11.25  9.0
16  10.0  12.25  9.0
17  11.0  13.25  6.0
18  11.0  13.25  6.0
19  10.0  12.25  8.0
20  10.0  12.25  8.0
21  11.0  13.25  7.0
```

Comment: выдает ошибку. ----> 2     frame = df.loc[window.index]
      3     rng = frame[frame["K"]<=frame["K"].iloc[-1]]

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: написала буквальный алгоритм того, что хочу получить. отредактировала вопрос

Comment: Я обновил ответ, добавив условие обработки фрейма. только у вас все равно на картинке зеленое окно охватывает 11 точек, а не 10.

Comment: исправила вопрос, неверная картинка удалена. Логику, написанной вами функции понимаю. Ошибка остается. Версия python 2.7.  При компиляции выдает предупреждение C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:6: FutureWarning: Currently, 'apply' passes the values as ndarrays to the applied function. In the future, this will change to passing it as Series objects. You need to specify 'raw=True' to keep the current behaviour, and you can pass 'raw=False' to silence this warning  и ошибку AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Ясно. у вас старый питон, от которого пора бы уже отказаться, а так же старая pandas. попробуйте в функции find_range() в первой строке написать `window=pd.Series(window)` (я дополнил ответ)

Comment: Спасибо.Завелось! От 2.7 отказываюсь, больно уж много всего переписывать :)